# nameerror: global name is not defined in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk
import test2

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("InterActMap")

def get():


    global CountryName
    CountryName = e1.get()
    global Day
    Day = e2.get()
    global Month
    Month = e3.get()
    global Year
    Year = e4.get()
    Monthint=int(Month)
    Dayint=int(Day)
    Yearint=int(Year)

    if CountryName == "germany" and Monthint == 8 and Dayint == 26 and Yearint == 1914:
    global a
        a = Button(root, bg = "red", text ="Battle of Tannenberg" , command=None)
        a.place(x=691, y=229)
        test2.register(a, Tannenberg)
```

left a few if's out here for brevitys sake but its the same thing with a few different battles, naming buttons a,b,c,d,e,f,etc.

```
def forget():
    a.place_forget()
    b.place_forget()
    c.place_forget()
    d.place_forget()
    f.place_forget()


canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1280, height=720)

country = Label(root, text = "Country")
country.place(x=5, y=5)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=60,y=5)

day = Label(root, text = "Day")
day.place(x=230, y=5)
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.place(x=260, y=5)

month = Label(root, text = "Month")
month.place(x=430, y=5)
e3 = Entry(root)
e3.place(x=475, y=5)

year = Label(root, text = "Year")
year.place(x=645, y=5)
e4 = Entry(root)
e4.place(x=680, y=5)



File = "map1.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(File))
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")

Button1 = Button(root, text = "Submit", command=get)
Button1.place(x=850, y=5)
Button2 = Button(root, text = "Clear", command=forget)
Button2.place(x=925, y=5)
Button3 = Button(root, text = "Exit", command=root.quit)
Button3.place(x=960, y=5)




canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I know the problem is that when I click clear all of the buttons dont necessarily exist so it throws an error...

```
NameError: global name 'c' is not defined
```

And then any buttons in forget() after the one that is not defined are not going to be cleared.

After looking around at similar questions I saw that defining the variable as something so that even if all the if statements arent true and all buttons are not created the variable at least has a value. That didnt work and I would just get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'forget'
```

I figured out a workaround, but its not really what I want

```
if CountryName == "germany" and Monthint == 8 and Dayint == 26 and Yearint == 1914:
    global a
        a = Button(root, bg = "red", text ="Battle of Tannenberg" , command=forget)
        a.place(x=691, y=229)
        test2.register(a, Tannenberg)
```

With this when I have multiple buttons/battles on the map, if I just click any one of them it clears the map. The same error is thrown but at least the map is cleared.
I've tried to make this work but I'm pulling my hair out, appreciate any help!

Comment: Why are you attempting to call a method on an object that may or may not be bound to a name?

Comment: can you fix indentation of `global a` in code block's please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to create an instance-level list that contains all your buttons. For instance:

```
button_list = []

if CountryName == "germany" and Monthint == 8 and Dayint == 26 and Yearint == 1914:
    a = Button(root, bg = "red", text ="Battle of Tannenberg" , command=None)
    a.place(x=691, y=229)
    button_list.append(a)
```

Then your forget command should be something like:

```
def forget(lst_to_clear):
    for button in reversed(lst_to_clear):
        button.place_forget()
        lst_to_clear.pop()
        # the reversal is to make sure popping the item out of the
        # original list doesn't break the for loop. You could just
        # as easily do:
        # # while lst_to_clear:
        # #     lst_to_clear.pop().place_forget()
        # but I find it a little less readable.
```

and your clear BUTTON should look like:

```
Button2 = Button(root, text = "Clear", command=lambda: forget(button_list))
Button2.place(x=925, y=5)
```

Comment: Anyone remember if the `lambda`s you assign to a `Button`'s `command` have an argument? I'm thinking it's given the mouse click event but now I can't remember. It's possible you'll have to make that `Button(root, text="Clear", command=lambda evt: forget(button_list))`

Answer (score 1):

So you could use the `try/except` handler in this case. Small example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def forget()
    for x in (a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        try:
            x.place_forget()
        except NameError:
            pass

a = Button(text = 'hi', command = forget)
a.place(x = 0, y = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

here the code will return a `NameError` because `b`, `c`, `d` etc. don't exist.The exception then deals with this, so you aren't interrupted.

hope that helps you!

Comment: The problem with this is that exceptions should really only be used for exceptional behavior. We're EXPECTING that not all of these buttons will exist yet, so we shouldn't be using exceptions to handle it.

Comment: @AdamSmith If exceptions are to be used for exceptional behaviour, and it gives a `NameError` otherwise, then it makes sense to use `try/except` by your logic (seems as if you are contradicting yourself). It does work and solves problem, so what is the issue? Your solution is probably more elegant though, I would say.

Comment: It would be exceptional that user input whose prompt requests a number fails `int`. It would NOT be exceptional that we clear a map whose spaces are not COMPLETELY full. In fact it would be quite unlikely that the "Clear" button is pressed only when the map is full.

Comment: @AdamSmith it is written [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) that `NameError` can be fixed using an exception handler. My solution will take whatever variables which exist and forget them, others will throw the `NameError`, which the exception handles, so why is this an issue to you?

Comment: @AdamSmith I think you are confusing the first and second parts of my answer, the first will deal with only one variable, the second deals with all variables, and if they don't exist the exception deals with it. I will try to edit and make my answer clearer

Comment: This solution worked too even though I liked the other one best. I've never really used try/except before and messing with this answer added it to my repertoire so thanks!